# Add TIMESTAMP field in SQLIte DB as per Indian Time

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I want to save the current time in SQLite DB. I am using the following code syntax -

```
private static final String CREATE_GROUP_MESSAGES_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
        + TABLE_GROUP_MESSAGE
        + "( "
        + GROUP_NAME
        + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, "
        + ENTRY_FROM
        + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_GROUPTEXT
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_ISSENDMESSAGE
        + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_GROUPIMAGEPATH
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + GROUP_COLUMN_TYPE
        + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + GROUP_COLUMN_KEY
        + " INTEGER primary key autoincrement, "
        + GROUP_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP
        + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

But the above is giving me the time as per the GMT basis. How to get/store the time as per GMT+5 or anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
GROUP_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP DATETIME DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime'))
```

And it will be defaulted to the user's localtime as opposed to GMT